# Ng-switch not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

I am using ng-switch as follows. Is this the proper usage of ng-switch? I don't want it to be in an array, because I am using it with a scope variable.

In my HTML I have defined it like below. The `userRole` being the variable I want my search to be based on, and in the `when` I have used values based on what my div tag contents should work with.

```
<div ng-switch on ="userRole">
  <div ng-switch-when="admin">
     [...]
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="user">
     [...]
  </div>
```

I am not able to access the functionality of ng-switch, and my entire content part just vanishes.

In my .js file I have defined the following:

```
if(loginModel.authorities[0].authority=="ROLE_ADMIN"){
  console.log("Me here");
  $scope.userRole="admin";
}
else
if(loginModel.authorities[0].authority=="ROLE_USER"){
  $scope.userRole="user";

}
else{
  $scope.userRole="guest";
}
```

But my screen does not show anything, which makes me wonder how should I use ng-switch. I do not want to use ng-hide / ng-show.

Comment: Show variable `$scope.userRole` in `console.log()`. Because `ng-switch` work as expected. Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/zcqsepxr/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a neat fiddle which i found on how ng-switch works.... The way you are using ng-switch is perfectly valid. I am guessing your `userRole` holds no value which is making it fail, can you double check on this.

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCheckCtrl">
   <div ng-switch on="loginData"> 
      <div ng-switch-when="false" ng-include="'login'"></div>
      <div ng-switch-when="true" ng-include="'logout'"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="login">
    <button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="logout">
    <button ng-click="logout()">Logout</button>
</script>
```

Controller code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function LoginCheckCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.loginData = false
    $scope.login = function() {
        console.log($scope.loginData  ? 'logged in' : 'not logged in');
        $scope.loginData = true;
    };
    $scope.logout = function() {
        console.log($scope.loginData ? 'logged in' : 'not logged in');
        $scope.loginData = false;
    };
}
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/jNxyE/